# How can I use Svelte in Google Colab

Tags: javascript, python, google-colaboratory, svelte

I see some cool Colab UI using Svelte in TensorFlow's [Lucid](https://github.com/tensorflow/lucid).

How can I setup and use Svelte easily in Colab?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/korakot/8aa31005b7a3a08c89298e73a835c39e) to setup similar to Lucid's %%html_define_svelte but a bit shorter.

But if you want to use the latest Svelte 3.0 with Rollup. Here's [another gist](https://gist.github.com/korakot/585e2cb211f81f75e35f303f437934a8).

The key parts are as followed. First is installation.

```py
from IPython.core.magic import register_cell_magic
!npm install -g rollup
!npm install --save-dev svelte rollup-plugin-svelte rollup-plugin-node-resolve &>/dev/null
```

Then a config and a boilerplate file.

```
%%file rollup.config.js
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
export default {
  input: 'main.js',
  output: {
    file: 'bundle.js',
    format: 'iife'
  },
  plugins: [svelte(), resolve()]
}

%%file main.js
import App from './App.html'
new App({ target: document.body })
```

Then the core `%%html` that you can use to define and display components.

```py
# overide %%html to get syntax highlight
@register_cell_magic
def html(line, cell):
  from IPython.display import Javascript
  if line:  # component
    with open(line.strip(), 'w') as f:
      f.write(cell)
  else:     # main
    with open('App.html', 'w') as f:
      f.write(autoimport(cell))
    !rollup -c &>/dev/null
    return Javascript('bundle.js')

def autoimport(cell):
  if '<script>' in cell:
    return cell  # manual import
  import re
  tags = re.findall('<([A-Z]\w*)', cell)
  imports = map("import {0} from './{0}.html'\n".format, set(tags))
  script = "<script>"+"".join(imports)+"</script>\n"
  return script+cell
```

Here's how you define a component

```html
%%html Nested.html
<h3>Paragraph</h3>
```

And call it quickly. I add autoimport for Capitalize tags, but you can import manually inside a <script> tag too.

```html
# main App.html to display
%%html
<h1>Header</h1>
<Nested/>
```